# How to center an element in a flex container but only when it is push to a new line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that has some text on the left and a button on the right. When they are on the same line I'd like to use `justify-content: space-between` but when the button gets pushed to a new line (due to a smaller screen), I'd like the button to be centred. Is there a way to do this without using media queries as the locale changes the button size and so the button gets pushed to a new line at different screen sizes.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXoaJQ)?

Resize the browser-width to emulate smaller devices.

### The trick

Margin left and right set to auto on the button.

### The code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <p class="text">Blasdfasdflasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
  </p>

  <a class="button">
    Submit
  </a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background: red;
  width: calc( 100% - 40px );
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  background: pink;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```